I've heard that nuclear thermal propulsion will get 800-900 ISP. Is this the same as it got on ground tests or is it a prediction of vacuum isp?
In other words is there potential for it to perform significantly better than expected when first tested in space?

Without knowing the source of the ISP figure and what it applies to, there’s no way to know for sure. “I heard that” is not sufficient context for  SE question.

That said, ISP for a proposed NTR engine is most likely a vacuum figure.

I find what Russell said likely. NTR like NERVA typically have low TWR so they are usually only thought of as useful for upper stages.

The NERVA NRX A6 engine developed by NASA and the AEC had a specific impulse of 869sec https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NERVA at Jackass Flats altitude 2800ft.
Vacuum ISP can be 5%-10% higher than sea level, but depends on nozzle design
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/340852962_Analysis_of_composite_propellant_energy_and_correlation_with_specific_impulse_at_vacuum_level/figures?lo=1 has data for chemical rockets but I could find no data on engines with ISP in the range of the NERVA
